# ANTLR4 TokenStream, getText method

Tags: java, token, antlr4

I'm trying to understand the ANTLR4 tokens and I have a question about tokens String represenation. Consider the following simple grammar:

```
grammar Test;

init: integer IDENTIFIER; 

integer: INT;

IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+;
INT: [0-9]+;
```

Generated parser's got this:

```
public static class InitContext extends ParserRuleContext {
    public IntegerContext integer() {
        return getRuleContext(IntegerContext.class,0);
    }
    public TerminalNode IDENTIFIER() { return getToken(TestParser.IDENTIFIER, 0); }
    public InitContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingState) {
        super(parent, invokingState);
    }
    @Override public int getRuleIndex() { return RULE_init; }
    @Override
    public void enterRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
        if ( listener instanceof TestListener ) ((TestListener)listener).enterInit(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void exitRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
        if ( listener instanceof TestListener ) ((TestListener)listener).exitInit(this);
    }
}
```

Now, in a generated listener we could use the parser itself if we pass it as an argument to a constructor as below:

```
public class TestListener extneds TestBaseListener{

    private final TestParser parser;

    public TestListener(TestParser parser){
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    @Override 
    public void enterInit(TestParser.InitContext ctx) { 
         TokenStrem stream = parser.getTokenStream();
         String str = stream.getText(ctx.init());
         //do some with str
    }
}
```

The question might be a dumb, but I don't see any profit from using `TokenStream::getText(RuleContext)` method. We could do just the same without introducing dependency on parser. Just call `ctx.init().getText()`.

Couldn't you explain why this method was introduced. For now, I don't see any helpful consequnces of using it.

Answer (score 3):

Involving `parser.getTokenStream()` then calling `stream.getText(ctx.init())` is simply for performance. The token stream associated with the parser is a cache and remembers the text for the `InitContext` directly. Yet through `ctx.init().getText()`, that's building text from all descendants, as is shown in the following [inplementation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.java#L154):

```
@Override
public String getText() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        builder.append(getChild(i).getText());
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```